# Keyset pagination with composite key

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination

I am using oracle 12c database and I have a table with the following structure:

```
Id       NUMBER
SeqNo    NUMBER
Val      NUMBER
Valid    VARCHAR2
```

A composite primary key is created with the field Id and SeqNo.

I would like to fetch the data with Valid = 'Y' and apply ketset pagination with a page size of 3. Assume I have the following data:

```
Id    SeqNo    Val    Valid
1     1        10     Y
1     2        20     N
1     3        30     Y
1     4        40     Y
1     5        50     Y
2     1        100    Y
2     2        200    Y
```

Expected result:

```
----------------------------
Page 1
----------------------------
Id    SeqNo    Val    Valid
1     1        10     Y
1     3        30     Y
1     4        40     Y
----------------------------
Page 2
----------------------------
Id    SeqNo    Val    Valid
1     5        50     Y
2     1        100    Y
2     2        200    Y
```

Offset pagination can be done like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Id, SeqNo OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

However, in the actual db it has more than 5 millions of records and using OFFSET is going to slow down the query a lot. Therefore, I am looking for a ketset pagination approach (skip records using some unique fields instead of OFFSET)

Since a composite primary key is used, I need to offset the page with information from more than 1 field.

This is a sample SQL that should work in PostgreSQL (fetch 2nd page):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Id, SeqNo) > (1, 4) AND Valid = 'Y' ORDER BY Id, SeqNo LIMIT 3;
```

How do I achieve the same in oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()` analytic function with ceil arithmetic fuction. Arithmetic functions don't have a negative impact on performance, and `row_number() over (order by ...)` expression automatically orders the data without considering the insertion order, and without adding an extra `order by` clause for the main query. So, consider :

```
select Id,SeqNo,
       ceil(row_number() over (order by Id,SeqNo)/3) as page
  from tab
 where Valid = 'Y';
```

P.S. It also works for `Oracle 11g`, while `OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY` works only for `Oracle 12c`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e296d7e733185cda7a80bba75c7ac03a)</kbd>

Comment: A smart solution utilizing rownum!

I checked your demo and see that your query selects all the pages.

Assume I only want the second page. Since I cannot refer to a field alias in WHERE clause I need to wrap your query into a subselect before using ```WHERE page = 2``` (updated from your demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0cdb5ae980792746502a9129b8179760). Would this affect the performance if I have a lot of pages?

Comment: @wtnyayja yes, you need a subquery to filter the desired page. I don't know about the performance situation, should be tested for a huge data set.

Comment: @wtnyayja I tested with a hugely populated (with records about 171 million) table just now, it was very performant provided one of the columns (Id or SeqNo) has a primary(or unique) index on it.

Comment: I just tested the with my actual db using ~15mil sample data and a page size of 1000. A composite index (composite primary key) was created for Id and SeqNo. It took 50 seconds for the first page and 55 seconds for the last page. A simple OFFSET approach took a shorter time of 28 seconds for the first page and 56 seconds for the last page. I wonder why...

Comment: Anyway marking this as the answer since your solution actually works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and then fetch rows using `fetch` and `offset` like following:

```
Select ID, SEQ, VAL, VALID FROM TABLE
WHERE VALID = 'Y'
ORDER BY ID, SEQ 
--FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY -- first page
--OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY -- second pages
--OFFSET 6 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY -- third page
```

--Update--

You can use `row_number` analytical function as following.

```
Select id, seqNo, Val, valid from
(Select t.*, 
Row_number(order by id, seq) as rn from table t
Where valid = 'Y')
Where ceil(rn/3) = 2 -- for page no. 2
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Your way works of course. But what I am asking for is a keyset pagination approach instead of the OFFSET way.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and share expected outcome?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I just updated the question.